# What's the best way make an "augmented" coefficient matrix?

Tags: math-mode, matrices

When studying systems of linear equations, it's nice to remind people that the last column of the coefficient matrix holds the constants.  This is often done in books by putting a vertical line between the last column and the next to last column.  What is a good way to do this in LaTex?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

One way to do this is implemented in the (free, in both senses!) online linear algebra textbook [Linear Algebra](http://joshua.smcvt.edu/linearalgebra/) by Jim Hefferon.  It's written in LaTeX and is open-source so one can download the book and its attendant style files.  One of them, called `linalgjh.sty` is about typesetting common linear algebra stuff such as augmented matrices and row reductions and the like.  The code for the augmented matrices is:

```
\newenvironment{amatrix}[1]{%
  \left(\begin{array}{@{}*{#1}{c}|c@{}}
}{%
  \end{array}\right)
}
```

and is used as:

```
\begin{amatrix}{2}
   1 & 2 & 3 \\  a & b & c
 \end{amatrix}
```

(note that the argument is one less than the total number of columns).  I guess that the `@{}`s at the start and end are to get the spacing right with the parentheses (mentioned by TH in a comment to fabikw's similar answer).

That style file has several other useful linear algebra macros that may be useful.

Comment: This example doesn't work for me. pdflatex says `Missing $ inserted.`

Comment: For latex newbies (like me): You have to put the example inside `\[` and `\]` latex codes.

Comment: I wanted to make it so the argument matched the total number of columns. A solution from my question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/571599/37581 showed that replacing {#1} with {\numexpr#1-1} does exactly what I wanted. I thought it would be helpful to others using this solution so thought I'd mention it here.

Comment: [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207457/question-about-used-in-array-environment) is a related question to the @{} used.

Answer (score 65):

If you build your own environment using array, you're on the safe side. I would extend an internal macro of `amsmath` using an optional argument.

**Advantages:**

- It extends several matrix environments at the same time (`matrix`, `pmatrix`, `bmatrix`, `Bmatrix`, `vmatrix`, `Vmatrix`).
- The names and meanings of those environments remain (not `apmatrix` etc.)
- Spacing etc. is the same like in `amsmath`.
- You could do more than just insert a vertical line (use color and alignment, for instance right aligned columns because of minus signs).
- If you omit the optional argument, it acts exactly like the `amsmath` environment.

**Caution:**

- Since you redefine an internal macro, it might not work if the original package changes its code. But `amsmath.sty` has not been changed for more than 10 years. If there's a change in the matrices later, you could adjust your own macro.

**Code:**

Here's the redefinition, just put it in your preamble after loading `amsmath`:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][*\c@MaxMatrixCols c]{%
  \hskip -\arraycolsep
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \array{#1}}
\makeatother
```

I had to use `\makeatletter` ... `\makeatother` because of the `@` in macro names.
The optional argument is the standard `amsmath` argument to `\array`. The original definition in `amsmath` is:

```
\def\env@matrix{\hskip -\arraycolsep
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \array{*\c@MaxMatrixCols c}}
```

So, there's not much that's been changed.

**Examples:**

Simple augmented matrix:

```
\begin{pmatrix}[cc|c]
  1 & 2 & 3\\
  4 & 5 & 9
\end{pmatrix}
```

More complex use, with different alignment, spacing and color:

```
\begin{bmatrix}[*2cr@{\quad}|@{\quad}>{\color{red}}r]
  a & b & 1  &  4 \\
  c & d & -2 & -3
\end{bmatrix}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Just remove the optional argument in brackets and you will get the standard `pmatrix` or `bmatrix`.

I've used this code and examples in a blog post in 2008: [An extension to `amsmath` matrix environments](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/maths/amsmath-matrix/).

If you don't wish to redefine that internal macro, you could give it a different name and build your `amatrix` environment on it exactly the same way that `amsmath` does with `pmatrix`.

Comment: From some quick testing it seems to do nothing to the starred versions of the matrix commands from `mathtools.sty`, but it's not like that matters much when you have full-featured array options available for all your matrix commands

Comment: I doubt anyone will see this, but is there a way to have a default alignment? E.g. Default to aligning the columns right even if no arguments are specified? If not, is there a way to specify general right alignment without putting as many r's as there are columns?

Comment: Note that this method will occasionally change the behavior -- `\begin{matrix} <newline> [s] & [t] <newline> \end{matrix}` will (despite the newline) interpret the `[s]` as the optional parameter. It's possible to wrap `[s]` in braces, or add `\relax` before `[s]` to fix the issue ____________________________________________________________________________________________ For documentation of `@ifnextchar`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4790 and `new@ifnextchar` see https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amsgen.pdf

Comment: Oh, I found an older comment from me. Anyway, you can change the default alignment to right by simply replacing `[*\c@MaxMatrixCols c]` with `[*\c@MaxMatrixCols r]` in the above declaration. Go figure.

Answer (score 27):

If you are using an array to input the matrix, you just have to specify something like

```
\left(\begin{array}{cc|c}  
 2 & 0 & 1\\  
 0 & 1 & 1  
\end{array}\right)
```

Comment: That's not a good way to do it. The spacing is wrong between the parentheses and the matrix.

Comment: Wouldn't `\bigl` and `\bigr` be better here?

Comment: As Andrew Stacey points out, @{} is all that's needed to fix up the spacing. That was eluding me.

Comment: I like that this answer does not require any unusual packages or difficult to understand hacks.

Answer (score 21):

If you would rather not override styles, you can create an augmented matrix using standard matrix commands like so:

```
\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 &\bigm| & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 &\bigm| & 5 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &\bigm| & -4 \\ 
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &\bigm| & -2
\end{pmatrix}
```

generating the following.

[image: An augmented matrix.]

Comment: Thank you! This will work in KaTeX.

Answer (score 11):

If for some reason (e.g. you try to make augmented matrix in Pages) other answers do not work, you can make an augmented matrix with two matrices inside delimiters of your choice:

```
\left[
  \begin{matrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
  \end{matrix}
  \left|
    \,
    \begin{matrix}
      4  \\
      4  \\
      4  \\
      4  \\
    \end{matrix}
  \right.
\right]
```

This code produces a matrix like this: 
[image: Matrix example]

You can modify space between delimiters by adding `\,` or other spacers.

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly, +1

Comment: I joined this community purely to upvote this answer.

Answer (score 9):

The `easybmat` package provides a way to add all sorts of lines between cells in a matrix, including dashed lines which I seem to recall being popular in my undergraduate linear algebra text.

Edit: Here's an example. I'm actually not thrilled about the spacing.

```
\[\left(\begin{BMAT}(@){cc.c}{cc}
a_{11} & a_{12} & b_1\\
a_{21} & a_{22} & b_2
\end{BMAT}\right)\]
```

Comment: The spacing between entries are adjusted using the optional argument of BMAT environment. For example, using  \begin{BMAT}[10pt] gives a much bigger matrix.

Answer (score 9):

The package `nicematrix` provides tools to draw mathematical matrices. There is no environment for augmented matrices in this package but it's easy to create one (compatible with the other features of `nicematrix`: dotted lines, blocks, exterior rows and columns, etc.).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment { pNiceMatrixAug } { }
  { \begin { pNiceMatrix } }
  { 
    \CodeAfter \tikz \draw (1-|\arabic{jCol}) -- (last-|\arabic{jCol}) ; 
    \end { pNiceMatrix } 
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\begin{pNiceMatrixAug}
a_{11} & a_{12} & \Cdots & a_{1n} & 0 \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & \Cdots & a_{2n} & 0 \\
\Vdots &       &        & \Vdots & \Vdots \\
a_{n1} & a_{n2} & \Cdots & a_{nn} & 0 \\
\end{pNiceMatrixAug}$

\end{document}
```

However, you need several compilations.

[image: Output of the first code]

---

EDIT: In order to have the ability to use `\CodeBefore` (and `\Body`) and `\CodeAfter` as in all the environment of `nicematrix`, and a color of the vertical rule which respects the key `rules\color` (and `\arrayrulecolor`), we must write an environment `{pNiceMatrixAux}` a bit more complicated:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment { pNiceMatrixAug } { }
  { \pNiceMatrix } 
  { 
    \tl_gput_right:Nn \g_nicematrix_code_after_tl
      { 
        \group_begin:
        \CT@arc@ % for the color of the rule
        \tikz \draw (1-|\arabic{jCol}) -- (last-|\arabic{jCol}) ; 
        \group_end:
      }
    \endpNiceMatrix
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\begin{pNiceMatrixAug}[rules/color=blue,left-margin]
\CodeBefore 
  \cellcolor{red!15}{1-1,2-2,4-4}
\Body  
a_{11} & a_{12}  & \Cdots & a_{1n} & 0 \\
a_{21} & a_{22}  & \Cdots & a_{2n} & 0 \\
\Vdots & \Vdots &        & \Vdots & \Vdots \\
a_{n1} & a_{n2}  & \Cdots & a_{nn} & 0 \\
\CodeAfter
  \line{2-2}{4-4}
\end{pNiceMatrixAug}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the second code]

Answer (score 5):

I would do something like this:

```
{
\centering
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
8 & 4 & 2 & 1 \\ 
64 & 16 & 4 & 1 \\ 
    \end{array}
\right)
$$
}
```

Comment: What's `\centering` doing? Also, `$$` is best avoided in LaTeX; prefer `\[..\]`.

Comment: Without the `\centering`, the matrix would be aligned to the left.

Comment: In math mode there is no alignment it's centered by default. See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to .

Comment: Indeed. But last time I used this, I could not have the matrix centered without using the `\centering` command. Very strange.

Answer (score 1):

A simple and clean solution for an augmented matrix can be obtained with the `tabularray` package.

[image: result]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{Abmatrix}{+b}{
\left[
\begin{tblr}{rowsep = {1pt}, colsep = {5pt}, column{1} = {leftsep = 0pt}, column{Z} = {rightsep = 0pt}, cells = {c}, vline{Y} = {dashed, 0.75pt}}
#1
\end{tblr}
\right]
}{}

\begin{document}

An augmented bmatrix:

\[
\begin{Abmatrix}
2 & -1 & 2 & 9 \\
1 & -2 & 4 & 12 \\
3 & 1 & -1 & 2
\end{Abmatrix}
\]

And another one:

\[
\begin{Abmatrix}
3 & 5 & 7 & 8 & 3 \\
6 & -2 & -3 & 12 & 5
\end{Abmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c}
1 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
-1 & 1 & -2 & -1 & 0 \\
1 & -2 & 3 & 2 & 0
\end{array}\right]
```

Comment: How is this answer different form fabikw's answer?