# How to format elementary row operations?

Tags: arrows, matrices

How do you write the elementary row operations in LaTeX? How do you show the use of the operations? Please include an example of interchanging rows, multiplying rows by a constant, and adding multiples of rows to each other.

Basically, I want to be able to have an arrow from one matrix to another and on top of it I want to be able to write the matrix operation that I am performing.

Comment: @subhamsoni I saw that, but I felt like it didn't accomplish my goals.

Comment: Please provide an MWE to help you. Your requirements lack a clarity

Comment: I actually found a solution in a different place: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3145/formatting-arrows-between-rows-of-corresponding-matrices

Comment: @okarin: I've just added a solution with a very simple syntax to the above mentioned post: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3145/formatting-arrows-between-rows-of-corresponding-matrices