# Writing Gauss-Jordan Transformation Matrix

Tags: matrices

I am having trouble writing procedure for Gauss-Jordan transformation matrix in LaTeX.

I want to write something like

```
      r2 - r1         r3-2r1
[A|I] -------> [A'|I'] ----->
```

and so on
with the corresponding transformations (e.g., r2-r1) on top of the arrows. Could you give me an example code of how to do this? I only know that I need `\bmatrix` for matrices with [], but I do not know how to split them in between with a vertical line |.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You might find the answers at this question useful as well: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2233/86

Answer (score 4):

With **amsmath** you can use

```
\xrightarrow{r_{2}-r_{1}}
```

that will produce an arrow wide enough to accommodate the thing on top.

In order to split matrices you need to use `array`

```
\left[\begin{array}{@{}cc|c@{}}
   <entries>
\end{array}\right]
```

With the `@{}` at both sides you'll get output similar to that of `bmatrix`.