# Vertical line in matrix using LaTeXiT

Tags: matrices

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the best way make an “augmented” coefficient matrix?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2233/whats-the-best-way-make-an-augmented-coefficient-matrix)

I am trying to make a vertical line in a matrix in LaTeXiT. I have read that it should be possible using the following:

```
\begin{bmatrix}{cccc|c}
1 & 0 & 3 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
```

But when doing so, this is my output:

[image]

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The `bmatrix` environment does not provide this facility (see section 4.1 of the [amsmath package documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)). You can use the `array` environment instead.

```
\[
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
1 & 0 & 3 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
\]
```

Comment: Possibly adding `@{}` at the sides: `@{}cccc|c@{}`, so as to give a similar result to `bmatrix`.

Comment: Thank you very much. The output of this is just like a `bmatrix`.

Comment: @egreg: Could you explain how the `@{}` works? I see that it has the effect of reducing the whitespace between the `[` and `]` and the matrix contents.

Comment: With `@{...}` you tell LaTeX to put `...` in place of the default intercolumn space, which is applied also at the start and end of the tabular.

Answer (score 44):

That won't work with the matrix environment from `amsmath`, however Stefan Kottwitz [wrote about a workaround for this on his blog](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/maths/amsmath-matrix/).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][*\c@MaxMatrixCols c]{%
  \hskip -\arraycolsep
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \array{#1}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{bmatrix}[cccc|c]
   1 & 0 & 3 & -1 & 0 \\
   0 & 1 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @barbarabeeton This would be a nice addition for **amsmath**, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Chou It's up to the person asking the question to decide which answer was most helpful for him or her. It's not always the highest voted answer that is accepted.

Comment: I know the rules here. You may take my words as an indirect praise; for your work helped me. :) By the way, I was not aware of the number of votes til your comment coming out.

Comment: The double-backslash line-break indicators seem to have morphed into single-backslash spacers. You may want to edit the code a bit.

Comment: @Mico Thanks, will edit. (It's a well known problem as you may know, http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7168/double-backslashes-disappear-from-code)

Comment: Aah, I had missed this recent meta.tex posting. I guess I'll need to be on the lookout for this issue in my own answers. Sigh.

Comment: On overleaf.com the vertical line does not work. It shows `[cc|c]` on cell 1 of the matrix.

Comment: @user3123159 The example in my answer worked fine when I tested it on Overleaf just now, so I would guess there is something else causing the problem. I suggest you make a small, complete example demonstrating the problem and ask a new question.

Comment: it works in the pdf view, but not in `visual editor`. Would be good if it works in the editor as well.

Comment: @user3123159 Oh, the visual editor, that's a different story. I don't think you can expect stuff like this to work there, I believe it uses JavaScript library called MathJax to render the math, and I don't think that could possibly parse all sorts of customizations people might do in their preambles to math stuff. But if you want a definitive answer to whether it is possible, ask Overleaf support.