# Matrix with vertical line in the middle

Tags: matrices

How can I produce the following output?

[image]

More specifically, I am not sure how to produce the matrix with the vertical line through the middle on the left of the ~ symbol.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Regarding the covariance matrix (the second argument of `N(.,.)`: As written, it would not appear to be a symmetric matrix. Is it possible that the `+` symbol in the first row is superfluous or that there's a `+` sign missing between the terms of the second row? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico, Actually the first term is T_{T-1}P_{T-1|T-1}T_{T-1}'+Q_{T-1}. The (1,2) entry is T_{T-1}P_{T-1|T-1} and the (2,1) is P_{T-1|T-1}T_{T-1}'. They are block matrices, so the transpose of the (1,2) entry is just the (2,1) entry. Perhaps there is a ' missing on the P on the (2,1) entry, but it isn't too important, I'm only interested on the LHS of the equation anyway :)

Comment: Thanks. I must confess I'd missed the very discreet space between the `Q_{T-1}` and `T_{T-1}` terms...

Comment: There is an easy workaround for this inside the "array" environment... I'll edit my answer then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To address just the left-hand term of the equation: It is possible to employ a `matrix` environment *inside* a `\left( ... \middle\vert ... \right)` construct. To force the item `\alpha_T` to be typeset flush left inside the (one-column) matrix instead of centered, just add `\hfill` to its right. (This works because the `matrix` environment builds on the `array` environment; by default, the columns of a `matrix` environment are centered, achieved by inserting `\hfil` on each side of each cell. Because `\hfill` is "more infinite" than `\hfil`, the contents of that row get pushed to the far left.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "matrix" environment
\begin{document}
\[
\left(
\begin{matrix}
\alpha_T \hfill \\ \alpha_{T-1}
\end{matrix}
\, \middle\vert \,
y_{1,T-1},\boldsymbol{\theta}
\right) 
\sim N \dots
\]
\end{document}
```

Addendum, posted after the OP clarified the structure of the covariance matrix: Similarly, the mean vector and covariance matrix can be written with `bmatrix` (short for "matrix with brackets", I suppose) environments, again employing the `\hfill` device to set some of the items flush-left.

[image]

```
\dots
\sim N\left(
\begin{bmatrix}
d_{T-1}+T_{T-1}\alpha_{T-1\mid T-1}\\
\alpha_{T-1\mid T-1} \hfill
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix} 
T_{T-1}P_{T-1|T-1}T_{T-1}'+Q_{T-1}  & T_{T-1}P_{T-1|T-1} \\
P_{T-1|T-1}T_{T-1}' \hfill          & P_{T-1\mid T-1}\hfill
\end{bmatrix}
\right)
\]
```

Answer (score 5):

Since there has been some issues with the vertical spacing inside the first matrix, I've found a specific workaround that is based on the division of the two columns:

- The first is considered as a separated `array` environment, so the two expressions will be typeset correctly.
- The second is a `standard` displayed equation that will make the third expression lie just bewteen the first two. Notice that this is achieved with the command `\middle` (thanks to @Mico for pointing this out).

This is the final MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
%
\usepackage{amsmath}
% This command adjusts the horizontal shrinking 
% between columns inside the environment.
\renewcommand\arraycolsep{2pt}
%
\begin{document}
%
\begin{equation*}
%
% Hhere starts the first "array" environment, now the delimiters are equal because
% the middle command  "( | )" separates the array from the standard environment 
% in order to make the third expression vertically centered.
\left(
%
\begin{array}{l}
 \alpha_T     \\
 \alpha_{T-1}
\end{array}
%
\middle\vert
%
\;y_{1:T-1},\,\boldsymbol{\theta}
%
\right)
%
\sim N
%
% Now there is the second matrix with the delimiter setting like
% ( [ ],[ ] )
%
\left(  % starting delimiter
%
\left[
 \begin{array}{l}
  d_{T-1}+T_{T-1}a_{T-1|T-1}  \\
  a_{T-1|T-1}
 \end{array}
\right],
% 
% Here is the second square delimited array.
%
\left[
 \begin{array}{lcc}
  T_{T-1}P_{T-1|T-1}T’_{T-1} & + & Q_{T-1}T_{T-1}P_{T-1|T-1}\\
  P_{T-1|T-1}T’_{T-1}        &   & P_{T-1|T-1}
 \end{array}
\right]
%
\right)     % Ending delimiter.
%
\end{equation*}
%
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

> [image]

---

**EDIT:**

Since two terms inside the second square-bracketed matrix were merged, this implementation should highlight the spacing:

```
 ...
 \begin{array}{lcl}
  T_{T-1}P_{T-1|T-1}T’_{T-1}+Q_{T-1} & & T_{T-1}P_{T-1|T-1}\\
  P_{T-1|T-1}T’_{T-1}                & & P_{T-1|T-1}
 \end{array}
 ...
```

Here is the correct output:

> [image]

Comment: Thanks! This is great. Just wondering, is there a way to achieve this output using the matrix environment?

Comment: @TrueTears Right now I'm experimenting with my compiler, but it takes time to achieve such a result. If I find the correct solution, I'll edit the answer; until then you may want to take a look at [this discussion](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33519/vertical-line-in-matrix-using-latexit), it will shed some light on the function of `\hline` inside a `matrix` environment

Answer (score 2):

Doing just the left-most matrix, seeing as that was your difficulty.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}[2013-10-15]
\def\stackalignment{l}
\begin{document}
\[
\left(\left. \Vectorstack{\alpha_T\\\alpha_{T-1}}
 \right| y_{1:T-1},\theta\right) = \ldots
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]