# caption in a table containing matrix

Tags: tables, captions, matrices

I put a matrix expression in a table. Now I'm trying to insert a caption, but I obtain an error and caption don't appear in my pdf. This is my code:

```
\begin{table*}
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
y_\triangle \\
y
\end{bmatrix}
\Large
=
\renewcommand\arraystretch{2}
\begin{bmatrix}[c|ccc]
- \frac{\omega_i C C_{dyn} H G}{1+C C_{dyn} H G} & \frac{\omega_i C C_{dyn}}{1+C C_{dyn} H G} & \frac{\omega_i}{1+C C_{dyn} H G} & - \frac{\omega_i C C_{dyn} H}{1+C C_{dyn} H G} \\ \hline
\frac{\omega_p G}{1+C C_{dyn} H G} & \frac{\omega_p C C_{dyn} G}{1+C C_{dyn} H G} & \frac{\omega_p G}{1+C C_{dyn} H G} & - \frac{\omega_p C C_{dyn} H G}{1+C C_{dyn} H G}
\end{bmatrix}
\normalsize
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1}
\begin{bmatrix}
u_\triangle \\
r\\
\omega \\
n
\end{bmatrix}
\]
\caption{Trasformata U_LFT del sistema}
\label{fig:ulft}
\end{table*}
```

In the preamble I inserted this code for insert vertical line in the matrix.

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][*\c@MaxMatrixCols c]{%
  \hskip -\arraycolsep
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \array{#1}}
\makeatother
```

Thanks to everybody for help

Comment: The instruction`\begin{bmatrix}[c|ccc]` can't be correct. Did you mean to write `\left[ \begin{array}{c|ccc}` instead -- and `\end{array}\right]` instead of `\end{bmatrix}`? What, incidentally, is the (mathematical) purpose of the vertical line, as well as of the `\hline` directive that's in your code?

Comment: @Mico Try adding the `\renewcommand*\env@matrix` code to your preamble, to see that `[c|ccc]` works,

Comment: Thanks for answer. I need vertical and horizontal line because this is transfer matrix of an automated system composed by 4 sub-system which I highlight using these lines. Using code I inserted in preamble I'm able to insert vertical line in matrix. I copy the code by another post in this forum [link] (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33519/vertical-line-in-matrix-using-latexit). My problem is on caption. It donesn't appear in my pdf

Comment: @TorbjørnT. - Thanks for pointing out the importance of the `\renewcommand*\env@matrix` code; I had completely missed it. That said, the `\hline` that's generated by the OP's code is much too long.

Comment: @Ruben - I've provided an addendum to my answer to suggest an approach that uses an `array` environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get rid of the error message generated by the caption, change `_` to `\_` in the argument of `\caption`.

You also should contemplate fixing several other issues. Do get rid of the font size changes within the formula, the `\hline` directive, and the changes to `\arraystretch`. Use `\dfrac` instead of `\frac` if you want larger fraction terms.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'bmatrix' environment and '\dfrac' macro
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page and text block parameters
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\[
\begin{bmatrix} y_\triangle \\ y \end{bmatrix}
%%%\Large
=
%%%\renewcommand\arraystretch{2}
\begin{bmatrix}%%%[c|ccc]
-\dfrac{\omega_i C C_{\mathrm{dyn}} H G}{1+C C_{\mathrm{dyn}} H G} & 
 \dfrac{\omega_i C C_{\mathrm{dyn}}}{1+C C_{\mathrm{dyn}} H G} & 
 \dfrac{\omega_i}{1+C C_{\mathrm{dyn}} H G} & 
-\dfrac{\omega_i C C_{\mathrm{dyn}} H}{1+C C_{\mathrm{dyn}} H G} \\[3ex] %%%\hline
 \dfrac{\omega_p G}{1+C C_{\mathrm{dyn}} H G} & 
 \dfrac{\omega_p C C_{\mathrm{dyn}} G}{1+C C_{\mathrm{dyn}} H G} & 
 \dfrac{\omega_p G}{1+C C_{\mathrm{dyn}} H G} & 
-\dfrac{\omega_p C C_{\mathrm{dyn}} H G}{1+C C_{\mathrm{dyn}} H G}
\end{bmatrix}
%%%\normalsize
%%%\renewcommand\arraystretch{1}
\begin{bmatrix} u_\triangle \\ r\\ \omega \\ n \end{bmatrix}
\]
\caption{Trasformata U\_LFT del sistema} % <--- change "_" to "\_"
\label{fig:ulft}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: If you must insert a vertical and a horizontal line in the 2x4 matrix, I suggest you do so by using an `array` environment, rather than a `bmatrix` environment. That way, you won't have `\hline` generating a line that's too long and ends up interfering with the square brackets.

```
\left[ \begin{array}{@{}c|ccc@{}}
-\dfrac{\omega_i C C_{\mathrm{dyn}} H G}{1+C C_{\mathrm{dyn}} H G} & 
\dfrac{\omega_i C C_{\mathrm{dyn}}}{1+C C_{\mathrm{dyn}} H G} & 
\dfrac{\omega_i}{1+C C_{\mathrm{dyn}} H G} & 
- \dfrac{\omega_i C C_{\mathrm{dyn}} H}{1+C C_{\mathrm{dyn}} H G} \\[2ex]
\hline 
% use '\mathstrut' to get a bit more vertical separation:
\dfrac{\omega_p G^{\mathstrut}}{1+C C_{\mathrm{dyn}} H G} & 
\dfrac{\omega_p C C_{\mathrm{dyn}} G}{1+C C_{\mathrm{dyn}} H G} & 
\dfrac{\omega_p G}{1+C C_{\mathrm{dyn}} H G} & 
- \dfrac{\omega_p C C_{\mathrm{dyn}} H G}{1+C C_{\mathrm{dyn}} H G}
\end{array}\right]
```

Comment: It was a stupid error by me. Thanks a lot!!! I was desperate.

Comment: thanks for your precious suggestions and for use your time for help me. Code is very "clean" now and result is amazing. I like it. Thanks a lot again!!