# How can I type A^-1 in the third Section

Tags: amsmath

Here is the code.

```
\documentclass[18pt]{article}  
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\title{An Introduction to Matrix}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
This is an example.\\
We will talk this in great detail later.
\section{Example Part}
$A=\begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 2 & -1\\ 
  -2 & 0 & 1\\
 1 & -1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$ 
\section{How to calculate the Inverse of A}
\end{document}
```

I want to add `$A^(-1)$` in `\section{How to calculate the Inverse of A}`.

Comment: Welcome! `\section{\boldmath How to calculate $A^{-1}$}`?

Comment: `\section{How to calculate $A^{-1}$}` (the symbol for the matrix should be the same as in the text).

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Thanks Bro. How can I draw a vertical line within Matrix?

Comment: @egreg No, it should *not*. kile, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33523.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat In mathematics,  and  generally denote *different* objects that *may* or not be related to each other.

Comment: @egreg It is up to you to suggest whatever, but all modern books typeset it in the way I propose. It is also not ambiguous. The other parameters like size and so on change as well, and that is *good* because it would look awful if it didn't.

Comment: @egreg How to type $A^{-1}$ with bold ?

Comment: @kile I tried to explain that you shouldn't embolden the A. It's mostly a question of style; you can follow the `\bm` advice, if you prefer to abuse notation.

Comment: Formatting carries semantic meaning for notation systems. Citing modern books as authority assumes (i) they know how to typeset, and (ii) they are *able* to typeset. All three propositions erode as *variation* becomes the template. In other words, stylisms come to predominate over communicative clarity. The tipping point will be how wide and deep the penumbra of meaning becomes. Statistically, I would expect a signal-decay shape for the curve, with a long fading tail.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat -- Whether or not a math expression in a bold section title is also emboldened is probably discipline-dependent.  In pure math, it's reasonably common to use both a lightface and boldface (same) letter to mean different things, so in a pure math publication, it would be wrong to embolden the letter to "agree" with the fact that a section heading is bold.  This is probably true also for theoretical applied math.  So AMS copyeditors would check, and reverse "global" emboldening if it changes meaning.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Certainly not in physics and many math journals and books. In fact, I am not aware of a single *modern*  journal or book where they would vary the font weight, and to me it simply looks wrong. I do, however, see attempts to avoid typing formulae in section headings, or to change the font weight in those. BTW I really appreciate your recent discussion of the differential d. 

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat -- There *is* value to avoiding formulae in section headings; it's even more important in titles.  The main reason is that aggregators of bibliographic information often can't handle such headings properly.  (Also the reason that "TeXorpdf" exists for bookmarks.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I agree with that but also would like to mention that `\boldmath` exists for a reason. Namely to allow one to have a consistent font weights in section headings and so on. Given that there is an agreement that the font size gets adjusted, I really do not understand the apparent disagreement on the font weight. (I just pulled out one of my favorite book to double-check what I already knew: `$p$-adic` really gets typset as `\boldmath $p$-adic` in the section title. It is a respected publisher, and the only books where I can see deviations are old, perhaps older than `\boldmath`.)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat -- To quote from the AMS style guide (section 3.1): "Math is always permissible in section heads, but displays are not. Any math in any head appears in math mode; it is not fonted to match the section head."  Tradition, long-standing.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I don't know what "it is not fonted to match the section head" precisely means. Does it mean that the font shape is not to be changed? Then I agree. Does it mean that the font size does not get adjusted? Or that the font weight does not get adjusted? In either of the cases I'd just break with the tradition.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat -- Font shape and weight are not adjusted.  Size *is* adjusted.  (Or, rather, size matching is automatic, not requiring explicit adjustment.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Not too bad. In two out of three points we agree. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding how to type `A^1` (or any other math expression) in a section heading, ..., it depends.

For traditional publishers of pure mathematics, the answer is "enter it as ordinary math", or `$A^1$`.  The American Mathematical Society's style guide says this (section 3.1):

> Math is always permissible in section heads, but displays are not. Any math in any head appears in math mode; it is not fonted to match the section head.

Translated out of jargon, this means that the font of a math expression is not changed in a bold (or small caps) heading; it should appear exactly as it does in text.

The reason for this is that, rather often, mathematicians use both a lightface and a bold version of the same letter in the same document to mean two different things.  (Sometimes, even more variations on a single letter are used!)  To embolden a lightface letter (as used in text) could therefore cause confusion, especially among less experienced readers.

That said, the practice is sometimes different in disciplines other than pure math, e.g., physics.  In such a case, `\boldmath` would serve to embolden the expression: `\boldmath ... $A^1$`.

A comment to the question states that this is the reason why `\boldmath` was created.  Not so.  Some fonts used for math are available only in lightface versions, and if a letter or other symbol in such a font is needed in bold form to make a necessary mathematical distinction, `\boldmath` (or better, `\bm` applied to only that character`) is a way to make the bold form available.

Comment: +1: What is a "display" in "but displays are not"?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner -- a "display" is, by definition, a chunk of math that is separate from the main, inline, text.  It is what is wrapped in `\[...\]`, the `equation` environment, or one of the `amsmath` multiline structures.