# Horizontal Line in LaTeX Matrix

Tags: matrices, arrays

I would like to reproduce the following table from the Wikipedia page on [Runga-Kutta methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods):

[image: Butcher Table]

As a result, I need the dividing lines. While this answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33522/295600 works great for the vertical dividing line, I don't know how to replicate the horizontal dividing line.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\hline` to create a full-width horizontal line in `array` and `tabular` environments.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

\begin{document}
\[
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.333} % default: 1.000
\begin{array}{@{} c | ccccc @{}}
0   & \\
c_2 & a_{21} \\
c_3 & a_{31} & a_{32} \\
\vdots & \vdots & & \ddots \\
c_s & a_{s1} & a_{s2} & \cdots & a_{s,s-1} \\
\hline
    & b_1    & b_2    & \cdots & b_{s-1}   & b_s 
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `\hline` after the `\\` that separates the penultimate and final lines of the matrix.