# Failure to produce nested matrix with shortcut macro

Tags: math-mode, matrices

I use a `\arr` macro as a shortcut for `bmatrix` environments.  In addition,
I use a hacked version of `bmatrix` (see: [What's the best way make an “augmented” coefficient matrix?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2233/)) so that it's easier to typeset augmented
matrices.

In theory, `\arr{SOMETHING}` should be equivalent
to `\begin{bmatrix}SOMETHING\end{bmatrix}`, and most of the time it is.  For
instance,

```
\[
\arr   {  2 &  5 }
\arr   {  1 \\ 2 },
\arr   {  1 &  3 }
\arr   {  1 \\ 2 }
\]
```

produces

[image]

However, when I put the lines above inside another `\arr`, in order to
obtain a nested matrix, it blows up

```
\[
\arr{
\arr   {  2 &  5 }
\arr   {  1 \\ 2 } \\
\arr   {  1 &  3 }
\arr   {  1 \\ 2 }
}
\]
```

[image]

with an error that says "incomplete \ifdim", whereas

```
\begin{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 5
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\ 2
  \end{bmatrix}
  \\
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 3
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\ 2
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{bmatrix}
```

works

[image]

Why?

Below follows the code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\makeatletter

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2233/
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][*\c@MaxMatrixCols r]{%
  \hskip -\arraycolsep
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \array{#1}}

\newcommand{\arr}[2][\@empty]{%
  \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{#1}
  \ifdim\wd\@tempboxa=0pt
  \begin{bmatrix}#2\end{bmatrix}
  \else
  \begin{bmatrix}[#1]#2\end{bmatrix}
  \fi
}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

\[
\arr   {  2 &  5 }
\arr   {  1 \\ 2 },
\arr   {  1 &  3 }
\arr   {  1 \\ 2 }
\]
% \[
% \arr{
% \arr   {  2 &  5 }
% \arr   {  1 \\ 2 } \\
% \arr   {  1 &  3 }
% \arr   {  1 \\ 2 }
% }
% \]
% \[
% \begin{bmatrix}
%   \begin{bmatrix}
%     2 & 5
%   \end{bmatrix}
%   \begin{bmatrix}
%     1 \\ 2
%   \end{bmatrix}
%   \\
%   \begin{bmatrix}
%     1 & 3
%   \end{bmatrix}
%   \begin{bmatrix}
%     1 \\ 2
%   \end{bmatrix}
% \end{bmatrix}
% \]
\end{document}
```

EDIT: unsimplified definition of `\arr` follows:

```
\newcommand{\arr}{\@ifstar\arr@star\arr@nostar}
\newcommand{\arr@nostar}[2][\@empty]{%
  \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{#1}\ifdim\wd\@tempboxa=0pt
  \begin{bmatrix}#2\end{bmatrix}
  \else \begin{bmatrix}[#1]#2\end{bmatrix} \fi
}
\newcommand{\arr@star}[2][\@empty]{%
  \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{#1}\ifdim\wd\@tempboxa=0pt
  \begin{matrix}#2\end{matrix}
  \else \begin{matrix}[#1]#2\end{matrix} \fi
}
```

Comment: Why not `\newcommand{\arr}[2][c]{\begin{bmatrix}[#1]#2\end{bmatrix}}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think it's because I have a starred version of `\arr` that uses no brackets.  Here I simplified by renaming `\arr@nostar` to `\arr`, but in reality is `\arr` is a "dispatcher" macro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\setbox` is a rather error prone way to test if an argument is empty, but here I don't think you need the test at all:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\makeatletter

% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2233/
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][*\c@MaxMatrixCols r]{%
  \hskip -\arraycolsep
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \array{#1}}


\newcommand{\arr}{\@ifstar\arr@star\arr@nostar}

\newcommand{\arr@star}[2][*\c@MaxMatrixCols r]{%
  \begin{matrix}[#1]#2\end{matrix}%
}

\newcommand{\arr@nostar}[2][*\c@MaxMatrixCols r]{%
  \begin{bmatrix}[#1]#2\end{bmatrix}%
}



\makeatother


\begin{document}

\[
\arr   {  2 &  5 }
\arr   {  1 \\ 2 },
\arr   {  1 &  3 }
\arr   {  1 \\ 2 }
\]
 \[
 \arr{
 \arr   {  2 &  5 }
 \arr   {  1 \\ 2 } \\
 \arr   {  1 &  3 }
 \arr   {  1 \\ 2 }
 }
 \]
% \[
% \begin{bmatrix}
%   \begin{bmatrix}
%     2 & 5
%   \end{bmatrix}
%   \begin{bmatrix}
%     1 \\ 2
%   \end{bmatrix}
%   \\
%   \begin{bmatrix}
%     1 & 3
%   \end{bmatrix}
%   \begin{bmatrix}
%     1 \\ 2
%   \end{bmatrix}
% \end{bmatrix}
% \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Correct. I don't know why I put the test in the first place.