# horizontal spacing in equations

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I am trying to replicate the same exact output as plain math mode would give
for a simple polynomial formula but using `\matrix` because I want to
right-align the terms in the polynomial or leave some of them blank. I can't use `\alignat` either for other reasons.

I have made some progress but the spacing is hard to get right.  In the
following picture you can see the output in plain math mode, using
`\alignat` and my attempt using `\matrix` (I use the convenience macro
`\arr`).

[image]

As you can see, my version is somewhat off.  I think the biggest error
is in the spacing around the equals sign.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2233/
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][*\c@MaxMatrixCols r]{%
  \hskip -\arraycolsep
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \array{#1}}
\newcommand{\arr}{\@ifstar\arr@star\arr@nostar}
\newcommand{\arr@nostar}[2][*\c@MaxMatrixCols r]{%
  \begin{bmatrix}[#1]#2\end{bmatrix}%
}
\newcommand{\arr@star}[2][*\c@MaxMatrixCols r]{%
  \begin{matrix}[#1]#2\end{matrix}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  C + 3D = 2
\end{equation}
%
\begin{alignat}{3}
  C  &+{}& 3D &={}& 2 & \notag
\end{alignat}
%
\begin{equation}
  \arr*[@{}r@{\,}c@{\,}r@{\,}c@{\,}r@{}]{
    C  &+{}& 3D &=& 2 \notag
  }
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you consider a tabular stack as an option?

Here I set it up with the one-time invocation:

```
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\stackMath
\setstacktabulargap{0pt}
\TABbinary
```

and then I invoke one of various forms of tabular stack using a syntax that mimics the tabular separators.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\stackMath
\setstacktabulargap{0pt}
\TABbinary
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  C + 3D = 2
\end{equation}
%
\begin{alignat}{3}
  C  &+{}& 3D &={}& 2 & \notag
\end{alignat}
%
\begin{equation}
  \tabularCenterstack{rcrcr}{
  C&+&3D&=&2
  }
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \tabularCenterstack{rcrcr}{
  C&+&3D&=&2\\
  4C&-&D&=&27
  }
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't know about tabular stack but it seems to do exactly what I want.

Comment: @ErnestA Great!  Glad to hear that my package can help you.  I should add that the `\TABbinary` essentially places a `{}` before and after each tabbed field, so that you don't have to add them manually as in `{}+{}`, etc.  There are other options that only auto-adds the `{}` to the left or the right of the field.