# Multiple equations in square bracket matrix

Tags: math-mode, matrices

When solving many equations you usually stuff them in matrices and solve them using Gauss-Jordan elimination. Where I come from, we write it like this and this is what should appear in my document:

[image: image description]

The gray parts of image are there for clarity and are not part of what I need. I just need `(n+1) x n` matrix with separation line. I will also need to display multiple of the matrices next to each other to show the GEM process:

[image: image description]

How can I do it?

Comment: That's really interesting, thanks. I'll try to figure out how to make the brackers square.

Comment: If you want to use `gauss`, there's a way for using square brackets. Just do `\begin{gmatrix}[b]` instead of `\begin{gmatrix}[p]`

Comment: The documentation for  the gauss package on page 8 explains how to change the delimiters http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/gauss/gauss-doc.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from Stefan's answer in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2244/46716

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][*\c@MaxMatrixCols c]{%
  \hskip -\arraycolsep
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \array{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \[ \begin{bmatrix}[*3c|c]
        2 & 5 & 0 & 7 \\
        3 & 0 & 4 & 2 \\
        4 & 2 & 6 & 3 \\
    \end{bmatrix} \Rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}[*3c|c]
        2 & 2 & 2 & 6 \\
        3 & 0 & 4 & 6 \\
        5 & 2 & 6 & 6 \\
    \end{bmatrix} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]