# Latex math align* alignment of more than 2 columns

Tags: math-mode, align, amsmath

I have this [image: aim] output (without the annotations and am somewhat confused about the aligning. This is the code for this example:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[headheight=0cm,bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[fleqn,leqno]{amsmath}
\setlength{\mathindent}{\labelsep}
\addtolength{\mathindent}{1.165ex}
\openup 1.25\jot


% increase matriced formating options https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2233/whats-the-best-way-make-an-augmented-coefficient-matrix
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][*\c@MaxMatrixCols c]{
    \hskip -\arraycolsep
    \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
    \array{#1}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
        \begin{align*}
            &\begin{pmatrix}[ccc|c]
                x & x & x & x \\
                x & x & x & x \\
                x & x & x & x \\
            \end{pmatrix} &\rightarrow
            \begin{pmatrix}[ccc|c]
                x & x & x & x \\
                x & x & x & x \\
                x & x & x & x \\
            \end{pmatrix}\\
            column1&column2&column3\\
            %
            &\begin{aligned}
                &\text{text} \\
                &r=-2 \\
                &\begin{pmatrix}[ccc|c]
                1 & x & x & x \\
                0 & x & x & x \\
                0 & x & x & x \\
            \end{pmatrix} &\rightarrow L=\varnothing \\
            %
                &\text{text:} \\
                &r=0 \\
                &\begin{pmatrix}[ccc|c]
                x & x & x & x \\
                x & x & x & x \\
                x & x & x & x \\
            \end{pmatrix} &\rightarrow L=
            \begin{pmatrix}[ccc|c]
                x \\
                x \\
                x \\
            \end{pmatrix}\\
                &\text{text:} \\
                &r=1 \\
                &\begin{pmatrix}[ccc|c]
                x & x & x & x \\
                x & x & x & x \\
                x & x & x & x \\
            \end{pmatrix} &\rightarrow L=
            \begin{pmatrix}[ccc|c]
                x \\
                x \\
                x \\
            \end{pmatrix}\\
            \end{aligned}\\
            &\text{text:}\\
            &\begin{pmatrix}[ccc|c]
                x & x & x & x \\
                x & x & x & x \\
                x & x & x & x \\
            \end{pmatrix} &\rightarrow L=
            \begin{pmatrix}[ccc|c]
                x \\
                x \\
                x \\
            \end{pmatrix}\\
        \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

I'd expect, that the first, second and forth elements would be aligned to where the `aligned` output ends (horizontally) and that the arrows inside the aligned environment would be horizontally aligned (which is in case of the first arrow not the case).

Somehow I don't get why this isn't what I'd expect it to look like, please help.

Comment: Your code cannot compile. Error message : Argument  of \\env@matrix has an extra }`.

Comment: Don't know how and why but somehow when copy-pasting the 1 was becoming a 3. Corrected the source code, now it works.

Comment: Consider using `shortintertext`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**
As follows from the OP comment,  (s)he like to have the following result:

[image]

(red lines indicate text area borders)

Where in the last equations row is shown the case if the real text is longer than one line. For aligning is used `alignat*` environment.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[headheight=0cm,bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[fleqn,leqno]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][*\c@MaxMatrixCols c]{
    \hskip -\arraycolsep
    \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
    \array{#1}}
\makeatother
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{alignat*}{4}
    &   \begin{pmatrix}[ccc|c]
        x & x & x & x \\
        x & x & x & x \\
        x & x & x & x 
        \end{pmatrix}   &&&  \rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}[ccc|c]
                                    x & x & x & x \\
                                    x & x & x & x \\
                                    x & x & x & x 
                                    \end{pmatrix}   \\[1ex]
    &   \rlap{text}                                 \\
    &   r=-2        &&& \\
    &   \begin{pmatrix}[ccc|c]
        1 & x & x & x \\
        0 & x & x & x \\
        0 & x & x & x 
        \end{pmatrix}   &   \rightarrow L & = \varnothing   &   \\[1ex]
    &   \rlap{text}     \\
    &    r=0        &&& \\
    &   \begin{pmatrix}[ccc|c]
            x & x & x & x \\
            x & x & x & x \\
            x & x & x & x 
        \end{pmatrix}   &   \rightarrow L & = \begin{pmatrix}[ccc|c]
                                                x \\
                                                x \\
                                                x
                                                \end{pmatrix}   &   \\[1ex]
    &   \rlap{text} \\
    &   r=1         &&& \\
    &    \begin{pmatrix}[ccc|c]
            x & x & x & x \\
            x & x & x & x \\
            x & x & x & x 
        \end{pmatrix}   &   \rightarrow L & = \begin{pmatrix}[ccc|c]
                                                x \\
                                                x \\
                                                x 
                                            \end{pmatrix}   &   \\[1ex]
    &   \rlap{\parbox[t]{0.9\linewidth}{text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text}}\\[1ex]
    &  \begin{pmatrix}[ccc|c]
            x & x & x & x \\
            x & x & x & x \\
            x & x & x & x 
        \end{pmatrix}   &   \rightarrow L & = \begin{pmatrix}[ccc|c]
                                                x \\
                                                x \\
                                                x 
                                            \end{pmatrix}   &   \\  
    \end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yea something like the second example but with \text{...} aligned to the left (aligned with the starting of the matrices)

Comment: @atticus, see edited answer. Is it now ok?

Comment: Seems alright. My I didn't knew, that align would create columns (uneven column aligned right, even column aligned left). (Just being curious, is there a way to get some kind of a "columnborder" for the align(at)(ed) environment (for debugging purpose) like for the pages with the showframe package?)

Comment: @atticus, as far as I know, no.

Comment: @Zarko If you are using `amsmath` then wouldn't it be better to use `intertext` and `shortintertext`?

Comment: @oliversm,to my opinion the `\shortintertext` from the `mathtools` package should be correct solution, however, OP require that start of text be aligned at left border of matrices (what cause unnecessary complications).