# How can I subtract 1 from the number of columns to repeat in array environment?

Tags: matrices, arrays, arguments

I was trying to create an environment for an augmented matrix and came across [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2238/37581), which gave me this code

```
\newenvironment{amatrix}[1]{%
  \left(\begin{array}{@{}*{#1}{c}|c@{}}
}{%
  \end{array}\right)
}
```

used as

```
\begin{amatrix}{2}
   1 & 2 & 3 \\  a & b & c
 \end{amatrix}
```

It works great, but it drives me nuts that the argument is one fewer than the total number of columns in the augmented matrix. I tried changing the `#1` to `#1-1`, but that does not seem to work. The closest thing I could find was the `calc` package, but that only works in certain circumstances, and this does not seem to be one of them.

So my question is: is there a way to either redefine the amatrix environment so that the argument matches the total number of columns in the augmented matrix? An even better solution would be one where I don't have to put in an argument at all, but I don't want to be greedy here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> An even better solution would be one where I don't have to put in an
> argument at all, but I don't want to be greedy here.

Be greedy! Here is a solution with `tabularray` package (and no argument at all):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{amatrix}{+b}{
    \begin{+pmatrix}[
        colsep=4pt,
        rowsep=0pt,
        vline{Y}={-}{solid},
        column{1}={leftsep=1pt},
        column{Z}={rightsep=1pt}
        ]
        #1
    \end{+pmatrix}%
}{}  

\begin{document}
    
    \[
    \begin{amatrix}
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        a & b & c 
    \end{amatrix}
    \]
        
    \[
    \begin{amatrix}
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
        a & b & c & d\\
        x & y & z & w
    \end{amatrix}
    \]
        
\end{document}
```

[image]

(Thanks to samcarter for her suggestion).

Answer (score 2):

This addresses your requirement of specifying the number of columns. `\numexpr#1-1` removes `1` from the input:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{amatrix}[1]{%
  \left(\begin{array}{@{} *{\numexpr#1-1}{c} | c @{}}
}{%
  \end{array}\right)
}

\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{amatrix}{3}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    a & b & c
  \end{amatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```