# Making an augmented matrix with multiple columns on the right hand side

Tags: math-mode, environments, matrices

I'd like to have an environment to make augmented matrices with multiple columns on the right hand side.
In [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2233/whats-the-best-way-make-an-augmented-coefficient-matrix/2238#2238) I found a nice environment that makes an augmented matrix with one column on the right hand side.

The code in that question is:

```
\newenvironment{amatrix}[1]{%
  \left(\begin{array}{@{}*{#1}{c}|c@{}}
}{%
  \end{array}\right)
}
```

Comment: How to have an augmented matrix environment that allows for multiple columns to the right of the vertical line.

Comment: Sorry, my bad...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution is good, but I propose a more intuitive syntax:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{amatrix}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{|}}m}
 {\left(\makeamatrix#1}
 {\end{array}\right)}
\NewDocumentCommand{\makeamatrix}{mm}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}
    {\begin{array}{@{}*{#1}{c}@{}}}
    {\begin{array}{@{}*{#1}{c}|*{#2}{c}@{}}}%
}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{amatrix}{4}
    a & b & c & d \\
    v & w & x & y
\end{amatrix}
\quad
\begin{amatrix}{3|1}
    a & b & c & d \\
    v & w & x & y
\end{amatrix}
\quad
\begin{amatrix}{2|2}
    a & b & c & d \\
    v & w & x & y
\end{amatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

You may need `\usepackage{xparse}` if you are running LaTeX prior to 2020-10-01.

Answer (score 3):

I adapted the above code to

```
\newenvironment{amatrix}[2][1]{%
  \left(\begin{array}{@{}*{#2}{c}|*{#1}{c}@{}}
}{%
  \end{array}\right)
}
```

which can then be used as

```
\begin{amatrix}[2]{2}
    a & b & c & d \\
    v & w & x & y
\end{amatrix}
```

The first argument is optional, and it indicates the number of columns to the *right* of the vertical line. The default value is 1. The second argument is mandatory and indicates the number of columns to the *left* of the vertical line.

Comment: Thank you, kind sir.