# Augmented matrix

Tags: matrices

Is it possible for me to insert a vertical dotted line between the last two columns?

[image]

```
\begin{pmatrix}
  1  & -1 &  0 &  0 & \cdots & 0 & a_1 \\
  0  &  1 & -1 &  0 & \cdots & 0 & a_2 \\
  0  &  0 &  1 & -1 & \cdots & 0 & a_3 \\
  \vdots  & \vdots  & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
  -1 &  0 &  0 &  0 & \cdots & 1 & a_n \\
\end{pmatrix}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the best way make an "augmented" coefficient matrix?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2233/whats-the-best-way-make-an-augmented-coefficient-matrix)

Comment: @AndrewStacey: The linked question doesn't have the dotted line requested by OP.

Comment: @SandyG It has a dashed one that I would be willing to bet could be converted to a dotted line, and it has a `nicematrix` solution that could be augmented with the answer below.  I would say that they are sufficiently similar that the answers here would be acceptable there and then they're all kept together for future questioners.

Comment: @AndrewStacey: fair enough.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a solution with `{pNiceArray}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[\begin{pNiceArray}{cccccc:c}
1&-1&0&0&\cdots&0&a_1\\
0&1&-1&0&\cdots&0&a_2\\
0&0&1&-1&\cdots&0&a_3\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
-1&0&0&0&\cdots&1&a_n
\end{pNiceArray}\]

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations because of the PGF/Tikz nodes used under the hood by `nicematrix`.

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 5):

Use last column as a 1 row matrix besides the row where you want `\vdots` centred

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,arydshln}
\begin{document}
\[
  \left(
    \begin{array}{@{} *6{c};{1pt/2pt}c @{}}
      1  & -1 & 0  & 0  & \cdots & 0 & a_1   \\
      0  & 1  & -1 & 0  & \cdots & 0 & a_2   \\
      0  & 0  & 1  & -1 & \cdots & 0 & a_3   \\
      \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
      -1 & 0  & 0  & 0  & \cdots & 1 & a_{n} \\
    \end{array}
  \right)
\]
\end{document}
```