# How I create this matrix with LaTeX?

Tags: matrices

[image]

The color doesn't really matter thanks

Comment: Unless there's an extra requirement of same column width it's just [math mode - What's the best way make an "augmented" coefficient matrix? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2233/whats-the-best-way-make-an-augmented-coefficient-matrix)

Answer (score 4):

If it's important to assign the same width to all four columns, whether or not they contain `-` ("minus") symbols, I suggest you employ the `wr` column type that's provided by the `array` package and measure the width of the cell that has the largest natural width. If the same-width-for-all-columns criterion is *not* important, just use the `r` column type for all four columns.

[image]

Either way, do make sure to apply math mode rather than text mode to the entries of the matrix -- this is done in code shown below by employing `array` environments -- and to suppress the default whitespace padding (via `@{}` particles) at the edges of the matrices.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}  % for '\widthof' macro
\usepackage{array} % for 'w' column type and '\newcolumntype' macro)
\newcolumntype{R}{wr{\widthof{$-1$}}}

\begin{document}
\[
\left(\begin{array}{@{} *{3}{R} | R @{}}
 2 &  1 &  3 &  1 \\
 4 &  4 &  9 & -4 \\
-2 &  5 &  3 & -1 
\end{array}\right)
\qquad
% same matrix, but with 'r' column type
\left(\begin{array}{@{} *{3}{r} | r @{}}
 2 &  1 &  3 &  1 \\
 4 &  4 &  9 & -4 \\
-2 &  5 &  3 & -1 
\end{array}\right)
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

With `{pNiceArray}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{pNiceArray}{*3r|r}
 2 & 1 & 3 &  1 \\
 4 & 4 & 9 & -4\\
-2 & 5 & 3 & -1
\end{pNiceArray}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
\left(\begin{array}{*3r|r}
 2 & 1 & 3 &  1 \\
 4 & 4 & 9 & -4\\
-2 & 5 & 3 & -1
\end{array}\right)
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: To make the result look more like a "standard" typeset matrix, you  may also want to suppress the whitespace padding at the left-hand and right-hand edges of the matrix. This may be done easily by changing `\begin{array}{*3r|r}` to `\begin{array}{@{}*3r|r@{}}`.

Comment: no, I may not ...

Comment: @Mico thanks for the explanation the meaning of `@{}`